# What is a 'restricted process' in MacOS?

Tags: macos

I have been trying to find out what does MacOSx mean by `restricted/unrestricted` process in its man pages

Example snippet from `dlopen` man page:

> Lastly, for old binaries, dyld will try some fallbacks.  If
> $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH was set at launch, dyld will search in those directories, otherwise, dyld will look in /usr/local/lib/ (if the process is unrestricted), and then in /usr/lib/.

My sample program to show different behavior on my 3 Mac machines

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define LIBM_SO "libcool.so"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *handle;
    double (*sine)(double);
    char *error;

   handle = dlopen(LIBM_SO, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
   dlerror();

   *(void **) (&sine) = dlsym(handle, "sin");

   if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("%f\n", (*sine)(4.0));
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This produces following output on Mac 13.4

```bash
./dlopen_example                                                                                                                                                                                                
dlopen(libcool.so, 0x0001): tried: 'libcool.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcool.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcool.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libcool.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libcool.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcool.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

Exact same program on Mac 13.5

```bash
./dlopen_example                      
dlopen(libcool.so, 0x0001): tried: 'libcool.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcool.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcool.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libcool.so' (no such file)
```

As can be seen, on Mac 13.5 `dlopen` is not searching in `/usr/local/lib`

I believe this is can be attributed to that man page snippet I posted about `unrestricted process` but have no clue what it means.

I have tried doing everything I can to make the environments identical. SIP is enabled on both, user is part of `wheel` group on both Macs, tried same command with `sudo` but no change in the behavior

I am stumped here and would appreciate any help. I came across these links [1](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/macos-hardening/macos-security-and-privilege-escalation/macos-proces-abuse/macos-library-injection) [2](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/blocking_code_injection_on_ios_and_os_x.html) but could not conclude on how it affects the behavior of this simple program I wrote.

Is this something specific on `Mac 13.4` ? 2 of my machines are at that version and there `/usr/local/lib` is being checked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941322/dyld-insert-libraries-ignored-when-calling-application-through-bash

Comment: As per that question, the reasons seem to be: (1) The binary is setuid/setgid
(2) Existence of __RESTRICT/__restrict section in the macho binary.
(3) The software has entitlements (hardened runtime) without com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables entitlement

Comment: I actually tried `setuid` bit on the binary for 'root' and then running with different user. On Mac 13.4, the behavior changes to ```dlopen(libcool.so, 0x0001): tried: 'libcool.so' (relative path not allowed in hardened program), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcool.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcool.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/lib/libcool.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)``` but then it says `hardened program`. Whereas on 13.5 it won't give any such message but would not look into `/usr/local/lib` by default

Comment: It seems there is something by default on 13.5 which is restricting `dlopen` to look into `/usr/local/lib`. The mystery is what ?